# SOLR QueryElevationComponent for Multi-tenant Support

Tags: solr, multi-tenant

Newbie question so please be nice. :)

Basically we need to implement editorial boosting for a multi-tenant SOLR environment wherein a pre-defined query from a user would always bring a certain set of documents at the top of the results.

A couple of challenges we have include:

- Given a single elevate.xml, we cannot indicate that a certain query text is intended for a particular tenant. Despite the existence of the tenantId in the index, there is no indication of that id in the elevate.xml file. We've thought of concatenating the ID to the query text (i.e. ipod_tenantID1) but I suppose the concatenation would not be traceable in the main query 'q'.
- We need to make updates to the elevate.xml seamless to the other active tenants. Is it correct that updating elevate.xml would require a SOLR server restart? If yes, is there a way to work around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you are using a single core/collection and the multitenancy is enforced by a `fq=customer_id:A` right?

Well, what about enforcing the multitenancy via a one collection per customer? This way each one can has its own conf (including elevate stuff).

About your second question, I did not check but probably a reload would be enough. If you go with the proposed solution, other tenants are not disrupted with the reload, as you deal with different collections.

Comment: Thanks @Persimmonium.

Right. Single core/collection for now and yes, fq=tenantID. 

We'll check the possibility of using multi-cores but are there any immediate disadvantages of going that route? Just want to make sure we're covering all bases.

Comment: @Shiro Kage Main disadvantage is a more complex setup to manage (multiple collections/cores). But there are more advantages too (better relevancy for instance, as terms in the index belong only to a tenant, in a single collection case, they are all mixed together).